# ng-repeat not showing any value

Tags: angularjs

This is my controller

```
mode.controller("array_l",['$scope',function($scope){
    $scope.items=[1,2,3,4,5];
    //console.log( $scope.items);
}]);
```

This is my HTML

```
<div ng-controller="array_l" ng-repeat="item in items">
  {{item}}
</div>
```

ng-repeat not showing any value
given controller and html

Comment: ...and where is your question?

Comment: definitely need more code for this.

Comment: "ng-repeat not showing any value"- this was the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move your `ng-controller` directive before your `ng-repeat` block.

Use `track by $index` in your `ng-repeat` to avoid problems with duplicate elements.

```
angular.module('mode',[])
    .controller("array_l",['$scope',function($scope){
        $scope.items=[1,2,3,1];
    }]);
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="mode" ng-controller="array_l">
   <div ng-repeat="item in items track by $index">
      {{item}}
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
{{item}}
</div>
```

Defiantly worth reading through the Angular docs.

Comment: this doesn't appear to answer the question.